# If then conditional logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to prove $A \Rightarrow B$
However, Suppose I know $B \Rightarrow C$ to be true.
Can I prove $A \Rightarrow C$ instead, and conclude that $A \Rightarrow B$ to be true?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let A = Betty is a horse; B= Betty is an cow; C= Betty eats hay.  So If Betty is a cow then she eats hay.  And you manage to prove that if Betty is a horse she will eat hay.  Does that mean if Betty is a horse, then Betty is a cow?

Comment: This is discouraging.  It appears to ask a question about logic and if-then connectives.  There is an answer that seems to be correct.  I say seems, because it makes sense to me, but I have been reading about logic for only a few hours.  No one may ever see this, but if you do and if you know why it is off topic, please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. What you hope to do commits the [Fallacy of Undistributed Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_undistributed_middle).

Quick counterexample to your argument:

$A$: This is a nickel

$B$: This is a dime

$C$: This is a coin

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is a slip in the question. If you know $C \to B$ (that way around!!) and can prove $A \to C$, then yes, evidently $A \to B$ follows.

But you can't derive that conclusion from $B \to C$ and $A \to C$!

(Example: put $A$ = Jack is over six foot six, $B$ = Jack is over seven foot, $C$ = Jack is tall. I know that $B \to C$; I know that $A \to C$. It most certainly doesn't follw that $A \to B$.)

Answer (score 0):

Why would

$A \implies C$

$B \implies C$

mean $A \implies B$?

Lizards $\implies$ lay eggs.

Birds $\implies$ lay eggs.

So Lizards $\implies$ Birds?